# Can a phrase have two meanings

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Let us say that someone is having a dispute with a company regarding the timely return of an item. They were told to return the item by or before the 18th of the month. They understood this to mean that they must have the item postmarked by the 18th to get a refund.

A week later they receive an email staying that they will not be refunded because the item came back later than the 18th.

Can the phrase, 'Please return by or before the 18th' have 2 meanings?

Comment: It could be interpreted several different ways.

Comment: Yes, a phrase can have two meanings.  No, this phrase does not mean "postmarked by".

Answer (score 1):

If there was no postal delay, and assuming that '*by or before*' is the same as '*on or before*' this would usually mean it needs to be in their possession at some point during, or before, the date stated.

However, with the delay of transit, you could interpret '*return the item*' as the act of putting it in the post, ending your part in the process (rather than it arriving at their end).

Unfortunately they've not been specific enough in their wording and it could be interpreted either way. If they wanted to avoid any ambiguity, they should have been clearer that it needed to be **there** on the 18th, rather than just in transit to them by the 18th.

> Please ensure the item has ***returned*** to us on or before the 18th... allow x days for postage etc....

'*Please return the item before ...*' instructs you to complete your part of the return

'*Return the item to us before ...*' indicates the item should be with them

**I think that their interpretation would be more common for returning items though**. Amazon prominently tells you the expected delivery date, not necessarily the expected shipping date. But this is just a personal feeling.

Also, please note this is a Language stack, not a Legal one, and so this may not be a legally suitable answer (there may well be a proper legal answer to this set down in law in your jurisdiction).

Comment: In my opinion an item has not been "returned" until it is actually received at the other end. The act of putting it in the post is part of the process, but doesn't guarantee that it will arrive at all - if the postmen loses it then it was not returned. I think one should assume the postmark date will not apply unless a company's returns policy explicitly mentions it.